# autoremove option doesn't work with apt alias

Tags: apt, bash, 14.10, alias

I have set up an alias for apt-get as apt, for convenience. This works fine, I can do

```
sudo apt install PACKAGE

sudo apt remove PACKAGE

sudo apt update
```

etc with no issues. However, the autoremove option doesn't work. When I do

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

I get E: Invalid operation autoremove

But when I do

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

it works fine. What's going wrong?

Comment: ~/.bash_aliases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Ubuntu 14.10, `apt` is a program installed on the system.
It does not currently support autoremove.

You may have to recreate your alias to override the builtin program.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man8/apt.8.html